# Creating VIEW statement in Jooq

Tags: java, sql, view, jooq

I am trying to create a view statement using Jooq, how could we do that?

Or do we have any other option?

Jooq version: 3.0.1

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Do you want to express a DDL `CREATE VIEW x AS SELECT ...` statement, or do you want to create a "view" in jOOQ, i.e. an object that models a subselect, but behaves like a table?

Comment: @Lukas, I wanted to create view, I think if I just wanted to access the created view, Jooq Generator tool could do it?

Comment: Yes, the generator deals with views just as if they were tables... I'll create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit support for `CREATE VIEW` DDL statements in jOOQ 3.1, although [some users on the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/h7U3Q9qhzGk) have already been challenging jOOQ to informally support it. Since this may be a common use-case, it may make sense to put it on the roadmap: [#2582](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2582)

Before any official support is added, you can still resort to plain SQL:

```
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(...);
ctx.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS {0};",
    select(a, b).from(my_table).where(...)
);
```

The above example makes use of [`DSLContext.query(...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.jooq.QueryPart...%29) to construct plain SQL queries that take jOOQ [`QueryPart`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/QueryPart.html) objects as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Creating views is not supported in jOOQ. As stated on the [jOOQ home page](http://www.jooq.org/):

- When not to use jOOQ:

  - ...
  - When you need to write DDL statements. jOOQ only supports DML statements.
  - ...

`CREATE VIEW` is DDL, not DML.

Comment: This is true, although using jOOQ for `CREATE VIEW` statement was recently challenged on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/h7U3Q9qhzGk). If you prepend a jOOQ-generated `SELECT` statement with a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` clause, there's nothing keeping you from using jOOQ to create views, in principle